# bash script to execute from where it was failed last time

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Can anyone tell me how to write a script to execute from where it was stopped last time. My bash script contains 24 script files which is executing sequentially. But if any one of the script fails, next time when i execute the script file i dont want the script to start from script1, instead it should start from where it was failed last time.  Please advise.

Comment: Sounds like you need a makefile dependent on some status files that get written as the make process progresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One crude way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Needs bash 4 or later, for `;&` to work
[ "$1" = "--frest_start" ] && rm statusfile

touch statusfile
read status < statusfile
[ "$status" = "" ] && status=0

case $status in
0) ./script1; echo 1 > statusfile ;&
1) ./script2; echo 2 > statusfile ;&
2) ./script3; echo 3 > statusfile ;&

# ....... & so on till

23) ./script24; echo 24 > statusfile ;;

esac
```

But doing it via `Makefile` seems a good solution too...

```
.NOTPARALLEL
.PHONY: all frest_start

all:
    make step1
    make step2
    make step3
    ....
    make step24

step%: script%
    "./$<"
    touch "$@"

frest_start:
    rm step*
    make all
```

Comment: Note that `;&` requires `bash` 4 or later.

Comment: If this works for you, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer... Also, for my info, let me know, which of the 2 options you used - bash/makefile?

Comment: Hi Anish, i've used the first method.. however i made some changes on that script based on my requirements..

Answer (score -1):

```
#mail.sh

function errortest {
    "$@"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error with $1" >&2
    fi
    return $status
}
errortest sh /home/user1/test1.sh
errortest sh /home/user1/test2.sh
```

whenever occur any error on script, it's give error on terminal.i tested on my machine same.

Comment: Don't call your function name as `test`. `test` is a `bash` built-in.

Comment: This just reports an error. It doesn't allow the script to resume where it left off after a previous error.